# set absolute position of image to object its bound to

Tags: c#, xamarin, absolutelayout

When a button is clicked on my XML, an image tag is created and on object is added to my list in my viewmodel.

This is the object that is created

```
    public unit(float x, float y, int team)
    {
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;
        this.team = team;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.rect1 = new Rectangle(x, y, 0.1, 0.1);
    }
```

When a different button is clicked, the unit.x is increased by 0.05.

I wish to bind my image tag position to the x and y of its unit object.

So if I click the buy button 3 times without clicking the move button, there should be 3 image tags perfectly on top of each other.

This is how my image tag is handled

```
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="units_list_view" ItemsSource="{Binding Unit_list}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Image Source="tank.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{Binding rect1}" />
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

It never moves even as x increases, and doesn't start at the x and y of the unit.

How can I set the absolute position of my image tag to the x and y value of the object it's bound to?

Here is all relevant code, just in case

https://github.com/tgmjack/absoloute_pos_prob

Comment: Items in a ListView will never appear directly on top of one another

Comment: what am i missunderstanding about <AbsoluteLayout> then?

i thought it was for absoloute positioning?

Comment: That only applies to the direct children of the layout.  Your Images are nested inside the ListView.  You can probably use a BindableLayout and get rid of the ListView